# include new nodejs module to reactJS project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui

I'm new to the reactJS/Node world. I created a project with `npx create-react-app myapp`.

After some hours playing around I found "material-ui".

So I downloaded it with `npm install @material-ui/core`. But it is not in my project.

I guess I have to include it or update.

I tried `ncu -u` and then `npm install` but it only updated modules already included in my project.

So my question is: how can I use material ui in my project which I created before downloading material-ui without creating a new project? Is there any cmdlet?

Comment: might be a silly comment but did you make sure that you were in the correct directory when you went to install?? if you type `pwd` in your terminal and it doesnt end with `/myapp` you are installing in the wrong place

Comment: I installed it global I guess. So if I create a new project it is included. My question is how to include it if I installed it "global"? material-ui is a good thing so I want to use it in more projects than only this one

Comment: Nah you have to install it as part of your project dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create your project using `npx create-react-app myapp` you need to go inside your project folder and install material ui as part of your dependencies

Step 1: `npx create-react-app myapp`

Step 2: `cd myapp`

Step 3: `npm install @material-ui/core`

Then you can look inside your project `package.json` file and you will see material ui installed